# Failed to upload picked image from gallery to php server

Tags: php, xamarin.forms, image-upload

I'm using PHP for a project that needs to be able to upload images from a gallery. For now I'm trying this:

I'm trying to pick image from gallery using `httpClient` and upload it to php serve. What works from is - pick image, convert mediafile to base64, but when it comes to php it recieves image file but doesn't add it to folder and always returns `failed upload`.

Where am I mistaken?

Here is my code:

```
       private async void browse_image(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
         var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
         MF = file;
         if (file == null)
             return;
         string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "." }; 
         var result = file.Path.Split(stringSeparators,        StringSplitOptions.None);
         img_path.Text = u.Username + code.Text + "." + result[1];
         var stream = file.GetStream();
         profile.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
         {
            return stream;
        });
       }
 
       public bool convert_image_to64(){

        var stream = MF.GetStream();
        byte[] filebytearray = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(filebytearray, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(filebytearray);
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(base64)){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
      }

      async Task upload_profile_page()
      {
        try
         {
          string result = "";
          var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
          postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("image",  base64));
          postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("filename", img_path.Text));

          var stringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);
          var content = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8,   "application/json");
          await DisplayAlert("", content.ToString(), "ok");
          HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

          var response = await client.PostAsync("http://example.com/upload_app.php", content);
          var FinalJSonResult =. (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
          if (FinalJSonResult.Count > 0)
            {
                var j = (JObject)FinalJSonResult[0];
                result = j.GetValue("result").ToString();
                if (result.Equals("0"))
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("0 ->", "failed to upload", "ok");
                }
                else if (result.Equals("1"))
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("1 ->", "uploaded image successffully", "ok");
                }

                else
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("1 ->", result, "ok");  
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Empty result" + "\n" + "size   of returned array:- " + FinalJSonResult.Count.ToString(), "Ok");
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "Ok");

            return;
        }

       }

       <?php // read JSon input
        $data_back = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); 
        // set json string to php variables
        $base = $data_back->{"image"}; 
        $filename = $data_back->{"filename"}; 
        $binary=base64_decode($base);
        $result1 = array(); 
        header("Content-type: application/json"); 
        try{ // Decode Image 
          $binary=base64_decode($base); 
          header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8'); 
          $result1 = array(); 
          // Images will be saved under '.../uplodedimages' folder 
          $file = fopen('.../uplodedimages/'.$filename, 'wb'); 
          // Create File 
          if(fwrite($file, $binary)==false){ 
          array_push($result1,array( 'result'=>"0")); 
          }else{
            $result1 = array();  
            array_push($result1,array( 'result'=>"1")); 
            }
          fclose($file); 

          }catch(Exception $e) {   
            array_push($result1,array( 'result'=>$e)); 
          } 
      echo json_encode($result1,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); 
      ?>
```

Comment: You need to debug your code.  I'd start by figuring out which line of the PHP script is failing, and why.  Then work from there to determine what the underlying problem is.

Comment: @Jason ,thanks for response , you are right , now when I debug php file , trying to echo $filename , gives me null , soo, I have to fix it first

Comment: Beside the problem you asked about, please respect C# naming conventions. This code might work but ...

Comment: thanks , I solved it :))

Comment: @EvZ , but what ??  can you show me more please

Comment: @HajerWael replace the 3 dots with a long explanation on why respecting a naming convention is important.

Comment: @EvZ Ok, thanks for your useful comment :)), I edited it , will consider this matter in next times